# How to obtain ANOVA table with statsmodels?

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression, statsmodels, anova

[image: Example code]

For the example in the link, I would like to also get an ANOVA table similar to what you get in SAS, where you have the Source (Model,Error,Total ) , DF , Sum of Squares, Mean Square, F Value and the p value all in one table.

Answer (score 3):

I've been searching for that for a while; I was using statsmodels' f_oneway function to perform a one-way ANOVA.  However, all that it returns is the f-statistic and p-value.

I got this from:
https://towardsdatascience.com/1-way-anova-from-scratch-dissecting-the-anova-table-with-a-worked-example-170f4f2e58ad

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
```

```
lm=ols('BY~E', data=df).fit()
table=sm.stats.anova_lm(lm)
print(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

@BarryDecicco's Answer should provide you with everything aside from MS. For MS just take the  sum_sq/df